# Does rule of three make sense for other than real numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

I'm currently working on a software tool which can make calculations based on the rule of three. I can make it more simple and just support real numbers, or I can make it "universal" to support virtually any kind of numbers (for instance complex numbers). My question is, does it make sense to do calculations based on the rule of three with other than real numbers? Could someone use this function with (for instance) complex numbers, or would this function have no practical use?

Comment: what is "the rule of three"?

Comment: A commonly used cross-multiplication mathematical method. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three

Comment: ok then yes, it also works in complex numbers

Comment: And can you imagine a practical use for this functionality? I'm asking because supporting multiple types of numbers would make the software a little less efficient and it is also a little harder to program, so I'm asking if it's worth it (if it has no practical use, then it's not).

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "practical" or, in other words, by your target user-base. The rule of three is just an algorithm to deal with a special kind of proportionality... For example: are your intended users elementary school kids? Then you most certainly won't need this feature. Are they high-schoolers? Then they might need to find a point on a complex line, so this might be useful. Are they mathematicians or engineers? The you will need a lot more than the rule of three, I'm afraid... ;)

Comment: Well i expect a wide range of users from high-schoolers to engineers or even mathematicians :). So I'll make it universal. Thanks.